# How to solve this question from Deterministic Finite Automata?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

With $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, give a DFA for $L= \{ w_1aw_2 : |w_1|≥ 3, |w_2|≤ 5\}$

In this question is it necessary for the the string $w_1$ to end with $b$ ? Otherwise how will we know from where the string $w_2$ is starting or $w_1$ is ending ?
How to design a DFA for this language ?

Comment: No it is not. I'd first design an nondet. finite-state automaton. That's quite easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it can help you

$DFA_{L}$: $(\{q_{1},q_{2},q_{3},q_{4},q_{5},q_{6},q_{7},q_{8},q_{9},q_{10},q_{11}\},\{a,b\},\delta,\{q_{1}\},\{q_{5},q_{6},q_{7},q_{8},q_{9},q_{10}\})$

$\delta_{1}:(q_{1},\{a,b\})\to q_{2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{2}:(q_{2},\{a,b\})\to q_{3} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{3}:(q_{3},\{a,b\})\to q_{4} $

$\delta_{4}:(q_{4},b)\to q_{4}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{5}:(q_{4},a)\to q_{5}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{6}:(q_{5},a)\to q_{5}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{7}:(q_{5},b)\to q_{6}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{8}:(q_{6},a)\to q_{5}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{9}:(q_{6},b)\to q_{7}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{10}:(q_{7},b)\to q_{8}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{11}:(q_{7},a)\to q_{5}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{12}:(q_{8},b)\to q_{9}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{13}:(q_{8},a)\to q_{5}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{14}:(q_{9},b)\to q_{10}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{15}:(q_{9},a)\to q_{5}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{16}:(q_{10},b)\to q_{11}\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{17}:(q_{10},a)\to q_{5}\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{18}:(q_{11},b)\to q_{11}\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$\delta_{19}:(q_{11},a)\to q_{5}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$

---

**$DFA_{L}$ diagram:**

[image]

Comment: Your DFA is not minimal. You can identify states 4 and 11.

Comment: Thanks @J.-E.Pin . yes we can combine states $11$ and $4$ into state $4$, [remove state $11$, add $\delta:(10,b) \to 4 $] then DFA is minimal.